# Matplotlib 3D hypocenter plot, reading xyz values from .txt file

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib

I am trying to learn python by doing. I have real world xy (lat long dd) coordinates and z (km below surface) values for about 500,000 earthquakes (hypocenter) from M 0.1 to 2.0. I chopped the data down to 10 rows of xyz values in a .txt tab delimited table. I want to plot the data in a 3d scatter plot rotatable box in matplotlib. I can use basic commands to read the data and the format looks fine. I am not clear if I need to read the data into a list or array for mpl to read and plot the data. Do I need to create an array at all?

I then want to plot the subsurface location of an oil well, given the xyz coordinates of vertices along the well bore (about 40 positions), do I need to create a polyline?. This data has the same general coordiantes (to be evaluated further) as some of the hypcenters. Which set of data should be the plot, and which should be the subplot? Also, I am unclear as to the "float" that I need given the 6 to 7 decimal places of he xy lat long coordinates, and the 2 decimal z coordinates.

Comment: Example code, please? Pretty difficult to answer without it.

Comment: from matplotlib exmples I believe a starting point is like this exmaple                             http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d scatter3d_demo.html                                                   I do not want random points but points but points from my file "xyx.txt" no header row, no id column. I have been reading the examples here but most relate to creating random numbers or values from equations. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: it is very hard to tell from your description that whether it is a data format/reading question or plotting question, or even a mathematical question (polyline etc). It'll be better if you give examples of your data files, with descriptions/pseudo-code explaining what goals you need to achieve. Reading mere text is HARD.

Comment: I know my question was not phrased well due to my lack of programming experience and total lack of knowledge of python and all of the modules. The .txt file was nothing but numbers to be treated as numbers, not text or a text string.

Answer (score 4):

Matplotlib is a poor choice for this, actually. It doesn't allow true 3D plotting, and it won't handle the complexity (or number of points in 3D) that you need. Have a look at [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) instead.

Incidentally, it sounds like you're doing microseismic? (I'm a geophysist, as well, for whatever it's worth.)

As a quick example:

```
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

# Generate some random hypocenters
x, y, z, mag = np.random.random((4, 500))

# Make a curved well bore...
wellx, welly, wellz = 3 * [np.linspace(0, 1.5, 10)]
wellz =  wellz**2

# Plot the hypocenters, colored and scaled by magnitude
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, mag)

# Plot the wellbore
mlab.plot3d(wellx, welly, wellz, tube_radius=0.1)

mlab.show()
```

[image]

As far as reading in your data goes, it sounds like it should be as simple as:

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt('data.txt').T
```

What problems have you run in to?

Comment: Joe, looks fantastic, just what I am trying to achieve. The problem that I ran into is that I a total newb when it comes to programming. I can work this out in ArcGIS with the gui, but I wanted to learn programming so I thought I would take this on as an example. I am a geologist in the oil and gas bus and was just curious if I could detect micro/mini seismic events when an operator was conducting a step rate test, or during water disposal. I would not have the operator setup microseismics for me, just wanted to analyze data already available via and existing, sophisticated seismic network.

Comment: I see now the free version of Enthought does not include mayavi, so this will have to be another work around.

Comment: Huh... It used to be. Guess it isn't anymore.  Regardless, mayavi is free and open-source. You can always install it seperately.  If you're on windows, and don't have a C compiler, have a look at python(x,y), which does include mayavi.

Comment: Removed Enthought, installed pythonxy, was able to generate your example. When I used the xyz...loadtxt).T example I receieved and error message "too many values to unpack" but this is a very small subset of data - about 20 rows of xyz mag values in a tab deliminted .txt file. I am not clear if I need to "load" or "import" the info as a list, create an array or what syntax to use. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: Well, if you have four columns, you'd need to unpack things into four variables (e.g. `x, y, z, mag = np.loadtxt('data.txt').T`)

Comment: Got the loadtxt working, the graph working, now I want to plot the directional survey for a particualr disposal well, how do I get the linspace function to buid a wellbore based on the xy-z coordinates from the well's directional surevey? Is there a manual anywhere where I can look this up? THANKS !!!!

Comment: `linspace` generates evenly spaced numbers between a min and a max (so `x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)` generates 10 points between 0 and 1).  Instead, you probably want to just load in the directional data using `loadtxt` (or something similar) just like you did for the event data.  As far as documentation goes, there are a number of ways to access the documentation for a python function.  Type `help(funcname)` at a python prompt, or you're in `ipython`, just type `funcname?`.  Most IDE's (e.g. spyder with python(x,y)) will display documentation as you type, as well. You can google it, too. :)

Comment: Did anyone get reasonable performance with 500,000 hypocenters? Not exactly 'rotatable'. Know of any other Python-based approaches to visualizing this much data?